# PyGame отслеживание объекта для взаимодействия с ним

Tags: python-3.x, разработка-игр, pygame

Всем привет. Столкнулся как оказалось с не тривиальной задачей. Суть следующая: Я использую PyGame библиотеку. Там есть метод `pygame.transform.rotate()`, при помощи которого можно поворачивать изображение на определенный угол. 
Хочу что бы изображение поворачивалось за объектом который движется(в будущем башня которая будет стрелять по врагам и поворачиваться в их сторону). Я догадываюсь, что тут вопрос скорее физики и математики, но ни как не могу понять в какую сторону смотреть и как это реализовать. 
Пример из кода самой библиотеки Pygame:

```
def __init__(self, image, startangle):
    ...
    self.original = image
    self.rotate(startangle)
def rotate(self, angle):
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original, angle)
```

Заранее спасибо за советы.